# Multiple IP to one server

Tags: php, ip, vps

I have a server with multiple IP addresses.
My customers point their domains to one server where my script/website is located.
This allows customers to have their own unique website.

Because of problems with Google ranking, I need to use my other available IP addresses.

Now, my question is how can customers have websites pointing to my different IP addresses, but running the script location from one IP.

For example, all the domains are now on IP: 11.11.11.11 (where the script/website is located).
Is there any way that, for example, a website that is pointed to my other IP 22.22.22.22, can run the script/website on 11.11.11.11?

Do I need to setup a virtual host, or is this possible with PHP?
I just don't know where to begin.

I have acces to WHM VPS optimized.

Answer (score 4):

1. IP addresses have nothing to do with Google rankings. *Maybe* they did at some point *in the past*, but not anymore. Google engineers have said this publicly several times. You might as well be sacrificing chickens to appease the mighty Google.
2. Not possible with PHP unless you want to write your own server software with sockets. [You don't.] Configure vhosts on *:80.